# I am unable to connect to MySQL on Pycharm even after installing pip and mysql connector properly

Tags: python, mysql

I have installed mysql connector properly and the command prompt even shows successful installation but for some reason Pycharm is showing error in installing the connector.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Coder Starts here

```
    Collecting mysqlconnector
      Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/7c/957e0c387d4c65df42ba56d5160456b0ff6f83f3cda122e18287605e3711/mysqlconnector-0.1.1.tar.gz
    Installing collected packages: mysqlconnector
      Running setup.py install for mysqlconnector: started
        Running setup.py install for mysqlconnector: finished with status 'error'
        Complete output from command "C:\Users\Farhan Hasnat\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\FARHAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\mysqlconnector\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\FARHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hnanue0h\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\Farhan Hasnat\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\include\site\python3.7\mysqlconnector":
        running install
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\FARHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\mysqlconnector\setup.py", line 47, in <module>
            'mysqlconnector = mysqlconnector.cli:cli',
          File "C:\Users\Farhan Hasnat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
            dist.run_commands()
          File "C:\Users\Farhan Hasnat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
            self.run_command(cmd)
          File "C:\Users\Farhan Hasnat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "C:\Users\FARHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\mysqlconnector\setup.py", line 20, in run
            raise Exception("You probably meant to install and run mysql-connector")
        Exception: You probably meant to install and run mysql-connector

        ----------------------------------------

    Command ""C:\Users\Farhan Hasnat\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\FARHAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\mysqlconnector\\setup.py';f=getattr**strong text**(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\FARHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-hnanue0h\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\Farhan Hasnat\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\include\site\python3.7\mysqlconnector"" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\FARHAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\mysqlconnector\
    You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: I have also checked other threads in here but could not come up with the proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"msql-connector-repackaged" should be "mysql-connector-repackaged", also try to pass in a database in your "myDB" variable (database must have already been created):

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="password",
    database="name of your database"
    )
```

Other than that, what edition of pycharm are you using? From my understanding pycharm ce edition doesn't support the use of database management systems such as Oracle, MySQL, SQL etc..., you need the professional version to do so.

I've been able to build databases with SQLite in pycharm, but that's built into python. I don't know how large the data your working with is, but if it's small you can resort to SQLite instead.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/relational-databases.html

Also, you can try other connection packages (CAUTION: IntelliJ, creators of PyCharm, may eventually remove them in order to preserve the mysql compatibility of non-free PyCharm editions) such as: mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python, mysql-connector-dd and mysql-connector-rf.

Comment: I am actually using the CE edition. I am just learning python so the database i am using is very small. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install the Python 3 and MySQL development headers and libraries like so:

```sh
$sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

Then run the pip install:

```sh
$pip install mysqlclient
```

Now you can add the package mysqlclient on Pycharm

Documentation: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python

:)